# How to print the cover of an eBook for binding?

Tags: book-binding, printing

I want to bind (or have bound) my own eBooks and I don't know how to print the designed covers (with a cover size of B4 paper). I want to replicate the kind of cover used by Amazon for paperback books like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201315963).  I am trying to identify the cover material and printing process they use.
For example, what type and specification of the paper, how it is printed, and any post-printing production steps, like coating or lamination.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119555/discussion-on-question-by-c-f-g-how-to-print-the-cover-of-an-ebook-for-binding).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find some information. In this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20L1I9zrLFM), the  paper they're printing cover on is **28lb bond** and then they're single-side **laminating each cover with 1.2mil gloss lamination**. "Thicker sheets are harder to fold and manipulate so a thinner sheet and lamination are ideal for these type of covers."

The main hard cover they are using is a pre-prepared hard cover that is itself one-side sticky and need not to any adhesive material.